Who is the dead person in the cemetery at the end of Daredevil S2E13?
At the end (55:25) of Daredevil Season 2 Episode 13 ("A Cold Day in Hell's Kitchen"), we are shown a dead person next to a grave that's been dug up.
Who is the person lying next to the grave?


The undertaker of The Sacred Saints Cemetery
In (43:44) we can see a glimpse of the undertaker of The Sacred Saints Cemetery finishing the burying of Elektra's coffin. The actor is uncredited in imdb.com

